# Перебрать массив элементов, не зная его размеров

Tags: java, массивы

У меня есть массив:

```
int[] array = new int[] {10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100};
```

Мне нужно вывести все элементы массива в консоль, я понимаю что для этого нужен цикл:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        System.out.println(array[i]);
}
```

А что если добавить несколько элементов, скажем так:

```
int[] array = new int[] {10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 101, 102, 103};
```

То как перебирать все эти элементы, постоянно менять условие i < ... Вот собственно вопрос, как перебирать массив элементов не зная сколько там элементов? :)

Comment: Сашко , спасибо я использовал ваш вопрос , на джаве .  И с легка переделал его , на СИ плюс плюс . Вы мне сильно помогли .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[@Сашко](/users/15213/%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%BE), Доброе время суток!

```
    int[] array = new int[] {
        10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104
    };

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(array[i]);
    }
```

Comment: Ооо, работает :)
Спасибо, @Ковальский!

Answer (score 0):

Для перебора всех элементов массива в Java есть как минимум три подхода:

#### Цикл с условием

Это привычный «сишный» способ. Просто проходим все индексы массива, перед
каждой итерацией проверяя, не дошли ли до конца.

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    System.out.printf("%d\t%d\n", i, array[i]);
}
```

#### Цикл по коллекции

Пишем вначале переменную, которая будет принимать значения элементов массива,
а затем через двоеточие — имя нашего массива. Если нужен индекс, его придётся
считать отдельно.

```
int i = 0;
for (int element : array) {
    System.out.printf("%d\t%d\n", i, element);
    i++;
}
```

#### Применение потоков

Начиная с Java 8 доступен специальный интерфейс [Stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/stream/Stream.html). Его удобно
использовать вкупе с лябда-функциями.

```
IntStream.of(array).forEach(element -> System.out.println("см. ==> " + element));
// если функции передаётся просто один аргумент, можно обойтись без стрелки
IntStream.of(array).forEach(System.out::println);
```

**Бонус:** последние два способа будут работать не только с массивами, а с
произвольного вида коллекциями.