# Как перебрать массив элементов, не зная его размеров?

Tags: c++, массивы

```
char peremen_t[]  =   {10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100};
```

Мне нужно вывести все элементы массива. Я понимаю, что для этого нужен цикл:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    qDebug() <<"peremen_t[i] " << peremen_t[i];
}
```

А что если добавить несколько элементов, скажем так:

```
char peremen_t[] =  {10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 101, 102, 103};
```

То как перебирать все эти элементы, постоянно менять условие `i < ...`? Вот собственно вопрос: как перебирать массив элементов, не зная сколько там элементов? :)

Comment: `количество элементов массива = sizeof(массива)/sizeof(одного элемента массива)`.

Comment: Либо в массиве должен быть явный терминатор...

Comment: Интересно получилось, такой же вопрос по [java](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/271044/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2)

Comment: Да он был взят за основу :3 ,  надеюсь автор вопроса на jave не сильно обидеться. Он "Сашко" мне сильно помог.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Имеется несколько подходов. Во первых размер массива можно вычислить по формуле
`sizeof( массива ) / sizeof( элемента массива )`. Например

```
for ( size_t i = 0; i < sizeof( peremen_t ) / sizeof( *peremen_t ); i++ ) 
{
    qDebug() <<"peremen_t[i] " << peremen_t[i];
}
```

Во-вторых, вы можете использовать цикл for на основе диапазона. Если вам при этом нужен индекс элемента, то вы можете определить его до цикла. Например,

```
size_t i = 0;
for ( auto x : peremen_t ) 
{
    qDebug() <<"peremen_t[" << i << "] " << x;
    ++i;
}
```

Также вы можете использовать цикл с итераторами. Например,

```
#include <iterator>

// ...

size_t i = 0;
for ( auto it = std::begin( peremen_t ); it != std::end( peremen_t ); ++it, ++i ) 
{
    qDebug() <<"peremen_t[" << i << "] " << *it;
}
```

И, наконец, вы можете написать шаблонную функцию, которая выполняет требуемую задачу. Например,

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
inline void f( const T ( &peremen_t )[N] )
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ ) 
    {
        qDebug() <<"peremen_t[i] " << peremen_t[i];
    }
}
```

Кроме того вы можете использовать какое-нибудь граничное значение в массиве. Например, для символьных массивов это может быть `'\0'` при условии, что действительные элементы массива не могут содержать этот символ, или какое-нибудь другое уникальное значение. Например,

```
char peremen_t[]  =   {10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 0 };
//                                                             ^^^ 
for ( size_t i = 0; permen_t[i] != '\0'; i++ ) 
{
    qDebug() <<"peremen_t[i] " << peremen_t[i];
}
```

Comment: Возможно, что в стандарте с++17 что-то изменилось, но теперь для определения размера(занимаемой памяти) массива по указателю нужно использовать _msize.

Answer (score 8):

Используйте современный C++ (с++11 и выше):

```
for( auto e : peremen_t ) { ... }
```

Comment: автор номер элемента выводит в дебаг) так номер получать некрасиво

Comment: @pavel для получение индекса можно добавить переменную. Но вообще стоит конечно различать ситуации: важны только значения, или ещё их индекс. `range-for` для ситуаций, когда индекс не важен. Собственно у автора вообще `[i]` это строка :)

Comment: @pavel номер элемента в range-based for можно получить через `boost::adaptors::indexed`.

Answer (score 7):

```
for( size_t i = 0; i < sizeof( peremen_t )/sizeof( peremen_t[0] ); i++ ) {
    /* .. */
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
///функция для подсчётa количества символов в строке
int counter(char In[])
{
    int i = 0;
    do{ 
    i++;
    }while(In[i] != 0);
    return i;
}
```

Comment: Можно весь подсчет сократить до одной строки `for(;in[i]; ++i);`

Comment: Впрочем да, Вы правы.

Comment: Причем тут вообще строки? `char` это не только символ, но ещё и число.

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb до одной строки `strlen`.

Answer (score 0):

На тему шаблонных функций и магии, [ideone](https://ideone.com/mBnyxl)

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
size_t len(T (*)[N]) {
    return N;
}
```

Comment: `std::size` в с++17

Comment: @DevNull оч остроумно, учитываю что ответ написан ещё в 2016)

Comment: а читают ответ в 2018. в русском so какие-то другие правила, чем в английском?